# ExtJs/.Net- Error converting batch Json data to .Net type

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I have a .Net mvc application with an ExtJS front end. I'm trying to update multiple records from a grid.  The records are being passed as a model with a `Ext.Direct` proxy, which matches this .Net type:

```
public class AgreementType
{
    public int AgreementTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

This is the method I'm passing into:

```
public ActionResult UpdateAgreementType(AgreementType at)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            success = _vendorRepo.UpdateAgreementType(at)
        });
    }
```

And here's the request payload:

```
{"action":"Main","method":"UpdateAgreementType","data":[[{"AgreementTypeId":10,"Value":"Spot PO","IsDeleted":false},{"AgreementTypeId":11,"Value":"PROCARD-test","IsDeleted":false}]],"type":"rpc","tid":12}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Project.Model.AgreementType' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.

When I try to pass one record, it correctly interprets the data into my type and updates successfully.  EDIT: Here's the payload for that:

```
{"action":"Main","method":"UpdateAgreementType","data":[{"AgreementTypeId":11,"Value":"PROCARD-test","IsDeleted":false}],"type":"rpc","tid":12}
```

I'm a bit of a noob with json, but I take it something is wrong with the data format.  I tried passing the values explicitly instead of just the model, but that didn't work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't just have an `AggreementType` you have a much more complex object described by that JSON payload. [Pasted into classes](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/) it looks something like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public Datum[][] data { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int tid { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int AgreementTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This payload works fine: {"action":"Main","method":"UpdateAgreementType","data":[{"AgreementTypeId":11,"Value":"PROCARD-test","IsDeleted":false}],"type":"rpc","tid":12}